# NGINX disregards listen ip:port commands

Tags: security, nginx

I have a reverse proxy configuration of NGINX:

Here are my configurations, I have edited out all the lines that IMHO are not relevant here.

Main Server:

```
server {
        listen       80;

    location / {
                include cors;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
      add_header Cache-Control $new_cache_control_header_val;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;

    }
}
```

And my second NGINX configuration

```
server {
        listen       127.0.0.1:8090;
}
```

The problem is, when I do in the broser:

http://myIP:8090/

I am getting to my server, while I have explicetly set the server to listen for this PORT only on THIS IP.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

> ... nginx first tests the IP address and port of the request against the
>   listen directives of the server blocks. It then tests the “Host”
>   header field of the request against the server_name entries of the
>   server blocks that matched the IP address and port. If the server name
>   is not found, the request will be processed by the default server. For
>   example, a request for www.example.com received on the 192.168.1.1:80
>   port will be handled by the default server of the 192.168.1.1:80 port,
>   i.e., by the first server, since there is no www.example.com defined
>   for this port.

So I would go a step further and theorize that `nginx` sees that there is only one server block on port `8090` and making it the `default_server` for that port.

You could test by adding a second server block with that port and your `myIP` and see if that returns something different.